# How to get the index in the original array when using np.argwhere on a slice?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using the function `np.argwhere()` on a subset of an array's elements but I need it to return the indexes of the elements satisfying the condition with respect to the original array and no the slice. Is there a way to do it?

Example code below:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
i = [0, 3, 6, 7, 8]
np.argwhere(A[i] < 8)

Output: array([[0], [1], [2]])
```

The output I desire is

`array([[0], [3], [6]])`

Comment: the slice doen't retain a record of the indexing, so you have apply any offsets yourself.  The numbers are all relative to the slice elements themselves.

Comment: `argwhere` is just `np.transpose(np.nonzero(...))`.  `nonzero` gives a tuple of arrays useful for indexing.  `argwhere` is just a (n,ndim)` array version of the same data.  Read both docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.argwhere` gives you the indices *in the slice*. We already know how to convert the index in the slice to the index in the array: the index `x` in the slice corresponds to the index `i[x]` in the array, so we just need to index into `i` with the result of `np.argwhere`!

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
i = np.array([0, 3, 6, 7, 8])

slice_lt8 = np.argwhere(A[i] < 8)
arr_lt8 = i[slice_lt8]
```

`arr_lt8` is now the desired value:

```
array([[0],
       [3],
       [6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
i = [0, 3, 6, 7, 8]
argA = np.argwhere(A[i]<8)
argList = [argA[idx][0] for idx in range(len(argA))]

desList = [i[idx] for idx in argList]
desListOfLists = [[x] for x in desList]
desArray = np.array(desListOfLists)
```

Since other readers may want slightly different output types, I've included three: list; list of lists, and ndarray:

desList produces

```
[0, 3, 6]
```

desListOfLists produces

```
[[0], [3], [6]]
```

desArray produces

```
array([[0], [3], [6]])
```

which was the original request.